# Hidden audio that play on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create some hidden audio player that start playing when you pass the mouse on them in a website page. But you must not see the audio player or the div, maybe with display none.

(Optional question, the important one is the first! When i open the page it should start a sound that will be interrupt by the other sounds on mouseover. Is it possible to make the first sound continue from when it stopped??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a div with `opacity: 0` with an onmouseover function. Remember to add a height and width to the div so the onmouseover event will only affect a certain area.

```
<div style="opacity: 0;" id = "player" onmouseover = "play()" ></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var audio = new Audio("filename");
function play(){
   audio.play();
}
//for pausing
//to play from where it left off, use the play method again
function pause(){
audio.pause();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do that with more than one Audio?

Comment: Simply create another Audio like this: `var audio2 = new Audio("filename");`.

Comment: Chrome has problems with audio, even though i followed some other stack overflow answers, it still get me this problem: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.